# Subclass of UIViewController shows black screen

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I created a Subclass of UIViewController in my Project and linked it to a View which is modal-pushed by the "RootViewController". I made absolutely no changes to the derived class, but when the "SecondView" is pushed it turns black every time. If i link that view to the standard UIViewController class everything works fine?

Since the "SecondViewController" is derived from UIViewController I can only guess that the Problem has to do with the alloc/init function but I have no idea where to start.

I can provide the sample code I have in front of me now if necessary.

This is the derived subclass:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self; }

- (void)loadView {}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; }

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); }

@end
```

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

Comment: Put the code please, it will help us a lot

Comment: Solved it.
By accident i stumbled upon a Topic in the "Related" section.
I don't know why but after deleting the 

    -(void) loadView

function everything works fine.
Still weird since the subclass was automatically generated by Xcode.

Comment: loadView either needs to call [super loadView] or you need to create a view and assign it to self.view. If the method doesn't do one of those things the view controller will not have a view -> black screen. If you're assigning your own view to self.view you should also set the background color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

FYI, the comment is automatically generated too.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

To this:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    // If you create your views manually, you MUST override this method and use it to create your views.
    // If you use Interface Builder to create your views, then you must NOT override this method.
}
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
-(void)loadView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame]; 

    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 100, 100)];

    [label setText:@"HAI"];

    [view addSubview:label];

    self.view = view; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the view to load before it "shows" up during the segue from IB you might want to try something like this in the destination view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```